# How do I make images within a slideshow responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, slideshow, slide

Context: I've hooked up tiny-slider.js to my site. I'm using it because it supports the "Variable width" function.

My problem is this: The slider i'm creating can't cut off images (needs to "contain" and not "cover"), which is why i'm using the variable width function. But I want all of the images within the slider to have the same height. The images are both portrait and landscape. When I resize the window/slider, the landscape images start resizing first before the portrait images, creating a weird looking slider that has varied heights. How can I make it to where all of the images have the same height, even when resizing? I just want the portrait images to start resizing when the landscape ones do.

My first thought was just to make the images have width: auto and height: [x]vh, however while that does solve my varying height problem, it causes my images to distort and squish together when the window is resized. I just can't seem to keep the height the same for all images while keeping the correct ratio of the images.

The only code i have affecting it right now (that's not part of tiny-slider.css) is just the options:

```js
var slider = tns({
  container: '.my-class',
  items: 1,
  slideBy: '1',
  autoplay: true,
  autoWidth: true,
});
```

Thank you!

EDIT - MORE INFO: I should mention i've hooked this up to a custom wordpress theme where the images within are changeable by the user. So there's no way I will be able to target specific images because the images could change at any time, and can be placed in any order.

Comment: If aspect ratio is width/height, take the image with the greatest aspect ratio and use that ratio for your slide divs. Then set the slides as background-images, centered and using `contain`. That way they should all have the same height, and some will have borders on their sides. If you keep the height relative to the width while the window resizes, it should work out perfectly.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for your comment, however i've added some more info to my post. the problem is the slideshow is fully customizable from the backend, meaning the image with the greatest aspect ratio could change at any time when the user changes images.

Comment: Ok, so determine the image when the user changes it and adjust accordingly.

Comment: And... maybe... sorry.. not a good day but still a valid point.

Comment: @EzraSiton did you mean to post a link?

Comment: This is a very famous CSS trick to keep the aspect ratio of thumbnails: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/ -- code example: https://codepen.io/overflow-team/pen/RRogPZ --- one more idea her (set the height to some value and the width to auto (See the thumbnails - swiper example)- https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/XWrBzMp